# Programmatically adding products to the cart with SCP

Tags: magento-1.8, configurable-product, addtocart

I am using the [SCP](https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple) extension so that prices are taken from the simple product and not the configurable.

My question is though how do I add a configurable product to a cart programmatically ensuring that it uses the correct prices?

```
$data=array(
            'product' => $product,
            'qty' => $params['qty'],
            'options' => $optData,
            'super_attribute' => $optConfigurableData
        );
$cart->addProduct($prod,$data);
```

This is how I normally would add a configurable product to the cart but this method uses the price from the configurable product and not the simple product

Comment: I suggest you take a look at what's passed to the CartController when adding a simple product (from a configurable page). 
`product` is your configurable, and then you should have an array of `super_group[]` whereby you give the simple product's ID and its associated quantity (be it 0 or more).

Comment: You may want to review the `getJsonConfig` in the configurable block for what data is required. https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple/blob/master/app/code/community/OrganicInternet/SimpleConfigurableProducts/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php#L6